# VKScript Создание массива JSON обьектов

Tags: vkontakte-api, vkscript

Выполнить код можно [тут](https://vk.com/dev/execute).
Нужно отправить в execute метод [update.Ads](https://vk.com/dev/ads.updateAds)

```
[{"ad_id":1234567,"cpc":13.255},{"ad_id":1234568,"cpc":0},{"ad_id":1234569,"cpc":12.155}]
```

Так не работает:

```
 return API.ads.updateAds({"account_id":123456789", 
      "data":{"ad_id":1234567,"cpc":3},
             {"ad_id":1234568,"cpc":5}});
```

Comment: непонятно. хотя б запрос написали какой выполняете....`"ad_id":ххххххх` не работает потому что `xxxxxx` строка а не число.... а строки пишутся в кавычках

Comment: Перенесите сюда **что** вы делаете, что хотите получить, что получаете и как пытались привести полученное к желаемому.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский обновил и доповнил, я отправлял числа, просто заменил id на ххххх

Comment: `Так не работает:` - когда что-то не работает, обычно пишут что они получают на выходе, например результат или ошибку с описанием.............`Выполнить код можно тут.` - вот боюсь именно этот код с `update.Ads` слишком специфичен, чтоб каждый мог его выполнить)) ... но нужен *output*, так или иначе